# What are report builder and fast report differences?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, fastreport

What are advantages and disadvantages of report builder and fast report? And what are their differences?

In fact, I am looking if there is any good reason to switch from report builder to fast report.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question...

Comment: @TechDog Actually I try to get some comparison between this two report designer software. I try to compare them and chose the best.